# Limit angle to segment

Tags: actionscript-3, math, trigonometry

I need to limit an angle so it fits into a segment. I have drawn and links to a diagram below to better describe what I am after.

I am trying to calculate this for a computer program, where I have an angle (*slope*), and a point (the mouse pointer). The distance does not matter to me, just the angles. If the point is within *b1* (green area) then that's fine. But if the point is within *b2* or *b3* (red or orange) areas, then the angle should snap back to the limit of the green area (along the line *s*).

[image: Diagram of my problem]
<sub>(source: [adamharte.com](http://sandbox.adamharte.com/dump/trigdiagram.jpg))</sub>

The main problem I am having in figuring this out, is snapping the angle to the correct side e.g. If the point is in the red area, then the angle should snap to the angle s on the red side and vice versa.

I am also having trouble because *s* could be any angle, so I am being tripped up because I can't just do something like this:

> if *a*(radians) is greater than
>   *s*(radians) then set *a* to the value of *s*

or I will get errors when the angle goes between zero and 2Pi.

So How would I work this out? Do I have to rotate everything back to a zero point or something then put it back when I have made my calculations?

Thanks for reading my questing.

Comment: I don't get it. If you have `a`, you'd just need to compare it to 0 and 180 degrees..

Comment: Since a is relative to s, if (a >270) a = 0 else if (a>180) a =180.

Comment: Oh, you don't have the angle a do you? Can you provide a little more context? Is the goal to restrict the x,y point to the green area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First code in an [ATAN2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)() function, to calculate the absolute angle for the point relative to horizontal plane. Then subtract the angle of the slope. if the result is <0 then snap to 0 and if the result is >180 snap to 180. The add the angle of the slope back to get your final angle

```
psi = (angle of slope)
a = atan2(x,y)
th = a-psi
if( th<0 ) { th=0; }
if( th>pi ) { th=pi; }
a = th+psi
```

try it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to make some assumptions since you don't specify how you define slope. Either way you should be able to get a theta from the equation.

Here is an example that does what you require. It was a fun challenge to get it to work and it should get you started. Note: one thing that helped me was *always* keeping angles between -pi and pi. I also use [vector projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) to get the line that is drawn to look like it correctly lies on the slope.

```
package
{
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;

public class CircleSnap extends Sprite
{
    private static const DEG_TO_RAD:Number = (Math.PI / 180);
    private static const RAD_TO_DEG:Number = (180 / Math.PI);

    private static const centerPoint:Point = new Point(200, 200);
    private static const RADIUS:int = 100;

    private var slope:Number;

    private var circle:Sprite;
    private var line:Sprite;

    public function CircleSnap()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);
    }

    private function addedToStage(event:Event):void
    {
        // choose a random slope (between -Math.PI to Math.PI)
        slope = (Math.random()*Math.PI*2) - Math.PI;

        // draw the circle
        circle = makeColoredCircle();
        addChild(circle);

        circle.x = centerPoint.x;
        circle.y = centerPoint.y;
        circle.rotation = slope * RAD_TO_DEG;

        line = new Sprite();
        addChild(line);

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, drawLine);
    }

    private function drawLine(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        line.graphics.clear();

        // calculate the angle of the line
        var lineAngle:Number = Math.atan2(
            stage.mouseY - centerPoint.y,
            stage.mouseX - centerPoint.x);

        var angleDiff:Number = (lineAngle - slope);
        if(Math.abs(angleDiff) > Math.PI)
        {
            // wrap the angle between -pi and pi
            var angleDir:int = angleDiff > 0 ? -1 : 1;
            angleDiff = (Math.PI*2 - Math.abs(angleDiff)) * angleDir;
        }

        // assume we just draw to the mouse position
        var destX:Number = stage.mouseX;
        var destY:Number = stage.mouseY;
        // if we are in the top area of the circle
        if(angleDiff < 0)
        {
            // calculate the length
            var xDiff:Number = stage.mouseX - centerPoint.x;
            var yDiff:Number = stage.mouseY - centerPoint.y;
            // we use Math.cos here to project the new line onto the slope
            var len:Number = Math.cos(angleDiff) * Math.sqrt(xDiff*xDiff+yDiff*yDiff);
            destX = Math.cos(slope) * len + centerPoint.x;
            destY = Math.sin(slope) * len + centerPoint.y;
        }

        // draw the line
        line.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x00FFFF);
        line.graphics.moveTo(centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y);
        line.graphics.lineTo(destX, destY);
    }

    private function makeColoredCircle():Sprite
    {
        var circle:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var bottomHalf:Sprite = new Sprite();
        circle.addChild(bottomHalf);
        bottomHalf.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
        halfCircle(bottomHalf.graphics, 0, 0, RADIUS);
        var topLeftQuarter:Sprite = new Sprite();
        circle.addChild(topLeftQuarter);
        topLeftQuarter.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
        quarterCircle(topLeftQuarter.graphics, 0, 0, RADIUS);
        topLeftQuarter.rotation = 180
        var topRightQuarter:Sprite = new Sprite();
        circle.addChild(topRightQuarter);
        topRightQuarter.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
        quarterCircle(topRightQuarter.graphics, 0, 0, RADIUS);
        topRightQuarter.rotation = -90;
        return circle;
    }

    // found this here: http://actionsnippet.com/?p=1515
    private function halfCircle(g:Graphics, x:Number,y:Number,r:Number):void
    {
        var c1:Number=r * (Math.SQRT2 - 1);
        var c2:Number=r * Math.SQRT2 / 2;
        g.moveTo(x+r,y);
        g.curveTo(x+r,y+c1,x+c2,y+c2);
        g.curveTo(x+c1,y+r,x,y+r);
        g.curveTo(x-c1,y+r,x-c2,y+c2);
        g.curveTo(x-r,y+c1,x-r,y);
    }

    // modified from halfCircle found here: http://actionsnippet.com/?p=1515
    private function quarterCircle(g:Graphics, x:Number,y:Number,r:Number):void
    {
        var c1:Number=r * (Math.SQRT2 - 1);
        var c2:Number=r * Math.SQRT2 / 2;
        g.moveTo(x+r,y);
        g.curveTo(x+r,y+c1,x+c2,y+c2);
        g.curveTo(x+c1,y+r,x,y+r);
        g.lineTo(x, y);
    }
}

}
```